# What is an object classifier and how does give a natural numbers object?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, higher-category-theory

According to a history of topos theory by McLarty, Blass (1989) showed that the existence of an object classifier over a given topos implies that the topos has a natural number object.

What is an object classifier, and how does it imply the existence of a natural number object?

ref:

Blass, A. (1989) Classifying topoi and the axiom of infinity. Algebra Universalis 26, no. 
3, 341-345

Comment: A link to the paper is http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/45657/12_2005_Article_BF01211840.pdf?sequence=1

Answer (score 1):

object classifier: a classifying topos for the one-sorted geometric theory having no non-logical symbols and no axioms, the theory whose models in any category are just the objects of that category.

Comment: This would be better as an edit to the question, rather than an answer.